# variable window calculation in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to count the frequency for a certain event from 1 to x in a series. then start again with 1.

The event is a number below or above zero.  It only want to count if the number is below zero.

What I have already coded:

```
import pandas as pd

numbers = pd.DataFrame({'E': [-0.66, - 0.32, 1.4, -0.45, -0.32, - 0.76, 1.1, 2.9]})
numbers['negative'] = numbers['E'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x > 0 else 1)
numbers['sum_negative'] = numbers['negative'].expanding().sum().astype(int)
numbers
```

output:

| E | negative | sum_negative |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -0.66 | 1 | 1 |
| -0.32 | 1 | 2 |
| 1.40 | 0 | 2 |
| -0.45 | 1 | 3 |
| -0.32 | 1 | 4 |
| -0.76 | 1 | 5 |
| 1.10 | 0 | 5 |
| 2.90 | 0 | 5 |

But, my output should look like:

| E | negative | sum_negative |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -0.66 | 1 | 1 |
| -0.32 | 1 | 2 |
| 1.40 | 0 | 0 |
| -0.45 | 1 | 1 |
| -0.32 | 1 | 2 |
| -0.76 | 1 | 3 |
| 1.10 | 0 | 0 |
| 2.90 | 0 | 0 |

I thought about ...

```
numbers['sum_negative'] = numbers['negative'].rolling().sum()
```

with the problem of variable window.

But I had no idea...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: As an aside: 0 is currently being categorized as negative (1). You might want to change `x > 0` to `x >= 0` if you "only want to count if the number is below zero".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [`groupby cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-cumsum) on groups based on where `negative` is 0:

```
numbers['sum_negative'] = numbers.groupby(
    numbers['negative'].eq(0).cumsum()
)['negative'].cumsum()
```

`numbers`:

```
      E  negative  sum_negative
0 -0.66         1             1
1 -0.32         1             2
2  1.40         0             0
3 -0.45         1             1
4 -0.32         1             2
5 -0.76         1             3
6  1.10         0             0
7  2.90         0             0
```

---

Explanation:

```
numbers['negative'].eq(0).cumsum()
```

Can be used to create groups separated by 0 values.

See with added to Frame For Side-By-Side Comparison:

```
numbers['group'] = numbers['negative'].eq(0).cumsum()
```

```
      E  negative  group
0 -0.66         1      0
1 -0.32         1      0
2  1.40         0      1
3 -0.45         1      1
4 -0.32         1      1
5 -0.76         1      1
6  1.10         0      2
7  2.90         0      3
```

Then each group can be accumulated based on the 1s and 0s in the `negative column:

```
numbers['sum_negative'] = numbers.groupby('group')['negative'].cumsum()
```

```
      E  negative  group  sum_negative
0 -0.66         1      0             1
1 -0.32         1      0             2
2  1.40         0      1             0
3 -0.45         1      1             1
4 -0.32         1      1             2
5 -0.76         1      1             3
6  1.10         0      2             0
7  2.90         0      3             0
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

numbers = pd.DataFrame({
    'E': [-0.66, - 0.32, 1.4, -0.45, -0.32, - 0.76, 1.1, 2.9]
})

numbers['negative'] = np.where(numbers['E'].gt(0), 0, 1)

numbers['sum_negative'] = numbers.groupby(
    numbers['negative'].eq(0).cumsum()
)['negative'].cumsum()

print(numbers)
```

The current `apply` function categorizes `0` as negative (1). The above `np.where` statement does so as well. If `0` should be categorized as non-negative (0) then replace with the following statement:

```
numbers['negative'] = np.where(numbers['E'].lt(0), 1, 0)
```